# firebase functions get error stream removed onCreate firestore event

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

I'm worried about this error on firebase functions,

I have a sendgrid dispatch on this function:

```
exports.mailDealings = functions.firestore
.document('dealings/current').onCreate(event => {
  // send mail
  const msg = {...}

  sgMail.send(msg);
})
.catch(result => {
  console.error("sendgrid error", result);
});
```

I was able to execute with success before but on one call, 
this function give me the error below:

```
{ Error: Stream removed
    at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
    at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8)
    at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:705:12 code: 2, metadata: Metadata { _internal_repr: {} } }
```

There should have an automatic retry for this error, right?
Or at least a method for turning this easy, like `result.retry(1000)`?

Comment: Are you sure your code is correct?  It doesn't look like you're returning a promise.

Comment: This seems to be an error with Firebase Functions right now and is being [looked into](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/firebase-talk/oza-JZMtXlo/Kge4Z0GaCQAJ).

Answer (score 2):

Same problem here (in many functions & randomly) since 3 / 4 days.
Apparently t disappears after deploy...for few minutes

```
Error: Stream removed
at ClientReadableStream._emitStatusIfDone (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:255:19)
at ClientReadableStream._receiveStatus (/user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:233:8)
at /user_code/node_modules/firebase-admin/node_modules/grpc/src/client.js:705:12
```

Answer (score 0):

From the [Google Groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/oza-JZMtXlo) on this bug:

> Hello all, Sebastian from the Firestore SDK team here. We believe this
>   issue is related to the recent update of the GRPC Client SDK and have
>   been running tests with GRPC 1.7.1. So far, we have not been able to
>   reproduce this issue with this older GRPC version.
>
> @google-cloud/firestore is now at 0.10.1. If you update your
>   dependencies, you will be able to pull in this release.
>
> Thanks for your patience.
>
> Sebastian

This seems to have fixed the issue for me!